# MicroOrm.Dapper.Repositories SqlGenerator param - where to get that?

Tags: dapper

Im trying to use the MicroOrm.Dapper.Repositories but the usage sample left me hanging on where to get the SqlGenerator object. It's sample documentation is:

```
public UserRepository(IDbConnection connection, ISqlGenerator<User> sqlGenerator)
    : base(connection, sqlGenerator)
{
```

Amy I using this right:

```
var conn = new MySqlConnection("connectionStringXYZ");
var generator = new SqlGenerator<User>();
var userRepo = new UserRepository(conn, generator);
```

which gives me internal server error 500.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do:

```
ISqlGenerator<User> userSqlGenerator = new SqlGenerator<User>(ESqlConnector.MySQL);
```

Preferably the generator should be a singleton, possibly an injected one.

But your error is an http error, so I suppose you are swallowing the real exception somewhere in your application. Find out the underlying reason.